# Geokettle transformation for FileGDB to SHP

Tags: coordinate-system, spatial-etl, file-geodatabase-api, geokettle

I want to transform FileGDB layer to Shapefile on Geokettle. Firstly i added OGR Input and than i added a Shapefile Output. And i entered parameters shown on the screenshot but i got errors for reading from FileGDB. What must i do for this transformation.
[image]

Comment: Have you compiled the required Esri FileGDB API against your OGR installation?

Comment: What error message did you get?